# aggregate multiple rows in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id=c(3, 3, 4, 5, 5)
a_2015 =c("abc", NA, NA, "abc", NA)
a_2016 = c("NA", "def", "abc", NA, "abc")
df = data.frame(id, a_2015, a_2016)

df

     id    a_2015    a_2016
1    3     abc       NA   
2    3     NA        def
3    4     NA        abc       
4    5     abc       NA
5    5     NA        abc
```

that means that if in column a_2015 is an entry than there is an NA in a_2016 or viceversa. So you can never have in the same row an valid entry in both columns a_2015 and a_2016.

I would like to aggregate the dataframe like

```
id    a_2015    a_2016
3     abc       def
4     NA        abc
5     abc       abc
```

I tried to solve it with aggregate but now I think I need something like apply, or? I am thankful for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` as well:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(tmp=paste(a_2015, a_2016, collapse = "")) %>% 
  mutate(tmp=gsub("NANA ", "", tmp)) %>% 
  separate(tmp, into = c("a_2015", "a_2016"), sep = " ")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id a_2015 a_2016
* <dbl>  <chr>  <chr>
1     3    abc    def
2     4     NA    abc
3     5    abc    abc
```

or even base R:

```
aggregate(df[,-1],  list(df$id), function(x) gsub("NA", "", paste0(x, collapse = "")))
  Group.1 a_2015 a_2016
1       3    abc    def
2       4           abc
3       5    abc    abc
```

Then you have to replace `""` with `NA` and edit the colnames.

Comment: @ Jimbou, with the aggregate command it also works with the whole dataframe (10.000 rows) - thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), id][]
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), id][]
#   id a_2015 a_2016
#1:  3    abc    def
#2:  4     NA    abc
#3:  5    abc    abc
```

#### data

```
id=c(3, 3, 4, 5, 5)
a_2015 =c("abc", NA, NA, "abc", NA)
a_2016 = c(NA, "def", "abc", NA, "abc")
df = data.frame(id, a_2015, a_2016)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, that's a perfect solution!

Comment: When I execute the commands on the whole dataframe (10.000 rows) I get the following error: Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), , lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]),  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (5). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (9891).

Comment: @hsteini  Perhaps in your original dataset the number of non -NA elements for  certain 'id' for each column will be different